# Extract duplicate row based on three columns power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, analysis

Hi i want extract the duplicated row based on three columns in power bi (power query).

If all column are same with other row then extract.

In this case the column are name, surname and phone1.

I show you an example :

- Thomas Mcjilly 3661378715 18 Rome
- Thomas Mcjilly 3661378715 35 Milan

I need to create a column custom in power query for  use in command description.

Thank you for help.

extract duplicate  and use a  table command description in a graph

Comment: Don't paste GPT code and please supply a sample table and expected outcome.

Comment: The example is in the text, is the code find the duplicated row insert in a custom columns a tag (maybe duplicated)

Comment: The example is poor. You need to supply sample input and desired output. For fun, I made a guess below

Comment: Ok, thank you. In my mind, I want to show in a command description the people who apply multiple times on the landing page. To do that I want to take 3 columns and confront with other to find the other info column of this duplicated application. Maybe create a custom column with tag to show the duplicated row,  i don't know i want find the best solution for show the duplicated apply. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potentially this helps:

remove all duplicate rows checking each column for matches

```
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source)
```

remove all duplicate rows by checking 3 columns

```
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source, {"Column2", "Column1", "Column3"})
```

check 3 columns and count number of occurrences. >1 means duplicates

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

Comment: Thank you i choose the last code, the group by and it work. THY